How to read the custom json values in KStream from kafka Topics
How can one effectively read JSON values from Kafka topics into a KStream in Kafka Streams? Despite trying various approaches, I've been unable to find the correct method to extract JSON object values within the stream topology
Topic JSON {"Id":20001234,"workbook":"CVF","state":"SUCCESS"}
KStream<Long, String> kStream = streamsBuilder.stream("TopicName",Consumed.with(Serdes.Long(), Serdes.String()));

error: State transition from PENDING_ERROR to ERROR
--Spring boot---
